# Python skip importing submodules that aren't available

Tags: python, django, import

I have a Python module that runs on a server and has some server specific imports (and functions).  I want to import and run it locally with a django command.  However, on my local machine, the server specific modules are not available.  I am currently using a try/except block in the server module but is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: try:except: is probably the most pythonic.

Comment: You could split the code into server modules and independent modules that don't have the troublesome imports. That removes the need for handling module not found. That may be better overall. If the module were not found on the server where its needed, you don't want to mask that error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd like to skip import of missing modules if you're running the module locally. The thing is that you don't want to silently skip importing them if you're running the module on a server and it happens so that required modules are missing.

Better approach is to configure environment and check it on runtime if you should import the modules or not.

It should go like this:

1. Configure env variable:

```
    export MY_RUNNING_ENV="production" // on server
    export MY_RUNNING_ENV="development" // locally
```

2. Check variable from code:

```
    import os
    env = os.getenv("MY_RUNNING_ENV")
    if env == "production"
        import "my_module"
```